# Facebook Analytics - Has 'Interests' been removed from the Demographic section?

Tags: facebook-analytics

I've started using Facebook Analytics again after a gap.

I can no longer see the interests of people who have clicked on my Ads.  Does anyone if Interests has been removed from the Demographic section of the UI?

If it's no longer available in the UI, is it available anywhere else?  Via the Insights API for example?

Answer (score 0):

I still see this section on my end. If you file a bug, we can investigate further.